# Grep multiple files whose file names are stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Consider the variable `files`:

```
$ echo $files
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

Is there a way to tell grep that it has to grep every file appearing in the variable for a single string? I've tried:

```
$ grep "string" "$files"
```

But I get a `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt No such file of directory` error. Its been a while since I used a  shell for work so I don't remember how to make this work.

Comment: `files=(*.txt); grep 'string' "${files[@]}"`

Comment: or just `grep 'string' *.txt` for filenames like that both should work, the only problem arises when filenames contains newlines, or a leading dash `-`

Comment: forgot to say that the variable is a product of previous pre-processing, the filenames that are there are highly specific and have a more complex configuration

Comment: Or simply do NOT quote `$files` so word-splitting occurs, e.g. `grep "string" $files` -- but NOTE none of the names in `$files` can contain whitespace. You are better off using an array as @Jetchisel suggests.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this seems to work really well for my specific case

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically [**5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time)

Comment: @MikeKatz45, then don't use a variable for storing data, use an array.

Comment: If your stuck just using a variable then convert that  into an array, `files=${files// /$'\n'}; mapfile -t array <<< "$files"; grep 'string' "${array[@]}"` but same caveat, fails on files with newlines and spaces/tabs.

Comment: @MikeKatz45 - it may work in this case with simple filenames that do not contain any whitespace -- but it is not the correct way to go. The array route is (if you are going to store the names to begin with). See the Bash FAQ #50 link above. It worth bookmarking the guides [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), and [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)  (especially the Pitfalls `:)` along with [**shellcheck.net**](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, the floor is yours dear sir.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a *list* of filenames stored in `files`, e.g.

```
files="1.txt 2.txt 3.txt"
```

When you quote `"$files"` (good job quoting your variable) and attempt to use `"$files"` with the `grep` command *word-splitting* on the contents of `$files` does not occur? Why? Quoting prevents *word-splitting* so `grep` tries to find the file named `"1.txt 2.txt 3.txt"` which of course doesn't exits and generates your error.

You can use `grep` with `$files` by simply using `$files` un-quoted -- but this is not the way to go. Why? When storing filenames for use with a command, you must ensure that the collection of files stored can handle all valid filenames. This includes filenames with spaces. If you attempt to use the unquoted method with:

```
files="file 1.txt file 2.txt file 3.txt"
```

Using `grep` (or any command) with unquoted `$files` will fail looking for 6-files, `file`, `1.txt`, `file`, `2.txt`, `file`, `3.txt`.

This problem is described and discussed at length in  [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically [**5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time). The solution is to store your filenames in an array (if you need to store them at all). As @Jetchisel points out, this can be handled simply by creating `files` as an array with:

```
files=(*.txt)
```

(or `files=([1-3].txt)` to limit the selection to `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`)

By using an array you can then use the quoted form of `"${files[@]}"` which will provide each of the filenames to the command individually quoted, e.g.

```
grep "string" "${files[@]}"
```

will expand to:

```
grep "string" "1.txt" "2.txt" "3.txt"
```

That way, regardless of what the filename is, and regardless of whether it contains whitespace, `grep` will see the proper filename. For example with:

```
files=("file 1.txt" "file 2.txt" "file 3.txt")
```

Using the quoted form of the array with `grep` will result in:

```
grep "strings" "file 1.txt" "file 2.txt" "file 3.txt"
```

So your original problem was caused by suppressing *word-splitting*, but your attempt to use a *list* of filenames was quite problematic on its own. If you need to capture a list of filenames in a variable, then use an array for the reasons above. If you can avoid storing them altogether and simply use the `grep` command with a glob such as `*.txt`, then you can avoid both issues to begin with.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Impressively detailed and patient explanation!